# Check time difference between timestamp and now in postgres

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

Column `health_check_at` time of last some service callback. I need to change the status column in the row if the difference between now and `health_check_at`.

My query:

```
UPDATE instances
SET status = 'STOPPED'
WHERE id = 1
    AND health_check_at IS NOT NULL
    AND localtimestamp - health_check_at > # somehow check if diff more then n minutes
```

How I can implement comparing between `current_timestamp - health_check_at` and 10 minutes for example?

And weekend not should be counted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtracting timestamps gives an interval.  So you need to an interval or N minutes. Just change your last line.

```
UPDATE instances
SET status = 'STOPPED'
WHERE id = 1
    AND health_check_at IS NOT NULL
    AND localtimestamp - health_check_at > &N * interval '1 min';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use functions like `extract(t1,t2)` or `age(t1, now())`.

[Extract](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)